# RxJS - retry or reset

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Let's say I have a `sequence` like this:

```
Rx.Observable
.interval(1000)
.subscribe(data => {console.log(data)})
```

With `operators`, how can I '`restart`' the sequence, meaning `unsubscribe` and `resubscribe`.

The real scenario is that the `sequence` is a socket stream, upon certain conditions we need to `unsubscribe` and `resubscribe`, kind of like the `retryWhen(errors)` works, but not with errors...would ideally be something like...`retryWhen(bool:Subject)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it using `switchMap()` because it automatically unsubscribes from the old Observable and subscribes to the new one. In this case we'll use only `.switchMap(() => source)`:

```
const subject = new Subject();

const source = Observable.create(obs => {
    console.log('Observable.create');
    obs.next(42);
});

subject.switchMap(() => source)
    .subscribe(v => console.log('next:', v));


setTimeout(() => subject.next(), 1000);
setTimeout(() => subject.next(), 5000);
```

This prints the following:

```
Observable.create
next: 42
Observable.create
next: 42
```

Just instead of `source` you'll have your WebSocket source (or whatever you have).

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but how could one do this without a subject? Is that possible?